# Hibernate one-to-one mapping does not generate one-to-one diagram on MySQLWorkbench?

Tags: java, xml, hibernate, hibernate-mapping

I am following a course on Hibernate. I have the following entity classes:

### User

```
package com.example.model;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class User
{
    private int id;
    private String name;
    private ProteinData proteinData;
    private List<UserHistory> history = new ArrayList<UserHistory>();

    public User() {
        setProteinData(new ProteinData());
    }

    public void setProteinData(ProteinData proteinData) {
        this.proteinData = proteinData;
        proteinData.setUser(this);
    }

    public void addHistory(UserHistory historyItem) {
        historyItem.setUser(this);
        history.add(historyItem);
    }
}
```

### ProteinData

```
package com.example.model;

import lombok.Data;

@Data
public class ProteinData
{
    private int id;
    private User user;
    private int total;
    private int goal;
}
```

Mapping is done using XML and as follows:

### User.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.example.model.User" table="USER">
        <id name="id" type="int" column="ID">
            <generator class="identity" />
        </id>
        <property name="name" type="string" column="NAME" />
        <one-to-one name="proteinData" class="com.example.model.ProteinData" cascade="save-update" />
        <list name="history" table="USER_HISTORY" inverse="true" cascade="save-update">
            <key column="USER_ID" />
            <list-index column="POSITION" />
            <one-to-many class="com.example.model.UserHistory" />
        </list>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

### ProteinData.hbm.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD 3.0//EN"
                                   "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-mapping>
    <class name="com.ugultopu.model.ProteinData" table="PROTEINDATA">
        <id name="id" type="int">
            <column name="ID" />
            <generator class="foreign">
                <param name="property">user</param>
            </generator>
        </id>
        <one-to-one name="user" class="com.ugultopu.model.User" constrained="true" />
        <property name="total" type="int">
            <column name="TOTAL" />
        </property>
        <property name="goal" type="int">
            <column name="GOAL" />
        </property>
    </class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

When I run the application, it works correctly. However, even though the relation between `User` and `ProteinData` is specified as one-to-one, when I generate a model diagram on MySQLWorkbench using the schema generated by Hibernate, the relation between `User` and `ProteinData` is depicted as one-to-many:

[image: Model diagram on MySQLWorkbench]

What might be the reason for this?

### UPDATE

This is the model diagram after making the following changes as specified in Naros' answer:

```
<!-- User.hbm.xml -->
<one-to-one name="proteinData" property-ref="user" ... />

<!-- ProteinData.hbm.xml -->
<many-to-one name="user" unique="true" not-null=true" ... />
```

[image: Model diagram on MySQLWorkbench after making the changes specified in Naros' answer]

Answer (score 0):

Most likely because there is no unique constraint defined on the `User` or `ProteinData` tables for the relationship between the two entities, therefore MySQLWorkbench believes its one-to-many.

One approach would be to specify the unique-constraint manually in the HBM mapping:

```
<hibernate-mapping>
  ...
  <database-object>
    <create>ALTER TABLE t ADD CONSTRAINT c UNIQUE (..)</create>
    <drop>ALTER TABLE t DROP CONSTRAINT c</drop>
  </database-object>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

Another approach would be to add unique constraints at the table level if you use JPA orm.xml

```
<entity class="User">
  <table>
    <unique-constraint>
      <column-name>proteinData_id</column-name>
    </unique-constraint>
  </table>
  ...
</entity>
<entity class="ProteinData">
  <table>
    <unique-constraint>
      <column-name>user_id</column-name>
    </unique-constraint>
  </table>
  ...
</entity>
```

Or specify this as part of an annotated class.

Comment: The first approach did not work. I have updated the question with the model diagram after applying the changes on the first approach.

Comment: I overlooked you using the `User` primary key at the primary key for the other entity.  It doesn't appear based on the XSD for the HBM mappings that you can effectively specify this like you can with annotations.

Comment: I updated my answer to include another way by specifying the create/drop statements for the unique constraint.  This is a manual declaration and can suffer from database agnostic issues if you use a database proprietary syntax, but may solve your issue.